# MYSQL Join query three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to retrieve distinct project_name in which any worker_id and their supervisor_id worked for the same project. I know the answer is bb, dd, and ee but don't know the query to retrieve this. Here is my query currently:

```
SELECT project.project_name, worker.supervisor_id, projectworker.worker_id
FROM project JOIN projectworker
on project.project_id = projectworker.project_id
JOIN worker
on worker.worker_id = projectworker.worker_id
order by project_name;
```

**retrieves:**

```
project_name | supervisor_id | worker_id
aa                   4           1
aa                   4           1
aa                   4           2
aa                   4           3
bb                   12          5
bb                   NULL        12
dd                   4           3
dd                   4           6
dd                   3           7
dd                   4           3
ee                   NULL        12
ee                   4           1
ee                   2           8
ee                   1           9
ee                   9           10
```

Comment: `SELECT project.project_name, worker.supervisor_id, projectworker.worker_id` ----> `SELECT distinct(project.project_name)` , there is no point keeping `worker.supervisor_id, projectworker.worker_id` when you want only the projects.

Comment: Yes but just want to illustrate problem at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
SELECT project.project_name

FROM   project 

       JOIN projectworker
       on project.project_id = projectworker.project_id

       JOIN worker
       on worker.worker_id = projectworker.worker_id

WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   projectworker 
               WHERE  project_id = project.project_id AND worker_id = worker.supervisor_id)

GROUP BY project.project_name

ORDER BY project_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT distinct project.project_name, worker.supervisor_id, projectworker.worker_id
FROM project JOIN projectworker
on project.project_id = projectworker.project_id
JOIN worker
on worker.worker_id = projectworker.worker_id
where worker.project_id = projectworker.project_id
order by project_name;
```

Comment: Or you can use worker.project_name = projectworker.project_name if project_name is present in both these tables.

Comment: project.project_id = projectworker.project_id
your question has project_id in worker table in it. What do you mean it doesnt? can you post the complete table design?

Comment: projectworker and worker are 2 separate tables: worker table has worker_id and supervisor_id but not project_id.